# I have a power source entering a ceiling light fixture…how do I wire it to a second fixture which connects to the switch?

Tags: wiring

I have power entering a ceiling light fixture, how do I wire from the first fixture to a second ceiling light fixture to the switch coming from the second fixture?

Comment: A picture and labeling will let us understand more.  If you just want 2 fixtures to work off the same switch, you may not have to run any cable to the switch.  However your description of what you want to accomplish is unclear,

Comment: Do you want the switch to control both lights or just the new second light?  Does a switch control the first light?  Will one switch control both lights or two separate switches, one for each light?   Connections should be easy, but we need to know exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wire with 3-wire + ground cable from the light with power to the other light and onward to the switch (In USA/Canada terms that's /3 cable, as ground is not counted in cable.) That is, unless you have unstated but important details like there's conduit running between the devices, in which case, use wires.

Unswitched hot goes from the power source to the switch; joined to the next unswitched hot wire, (black in a /3 cable, by convention) but not otherwise connected to at each device it passes. At the switch location, unswitched hot goes into the switch and comes out as switched hot, which is fed back on the switched hot wire (red in a /3 cable, by convention) to each device to be switched, and joined to the device's hot wire. Device neutrals connect to the neutral wire (white in a /3 cable by code) and box (if metallic) and device ground connects to the cable ground (bare or green by code.)

Comment: Only need /2 from first light to second light. /3 from second light to second switch.

Comment: Power enters at "first light" (furthest from switch) - if both lights are to be switched, then /3 is needed from first, to second, to switch. Question is vague on that point.

Comment: Yeah, it is vague. My take on it was: first ceiling box = incoming power, light fixture, cable to switch 1; second ceiling box = new light fixture, adding power from fixture 1 box to fixture 2 box, adding switch just for fixture 2.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   My take also, but do need OP to explain fully what they want.